# Resetting HTML Range Input in JS doesn't move displayed slider

Tags: javascript, html, range

#### HTML:

```
<input type = "range" id = "rngIntro" min = "0" max = "5" value = "0">
```

#### JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("rngIntro").value = "0";
```

Here's a piece of my code that basically resets the `rngIntro` HTML range slider. It changes the value of it when the function is called, but it leaves the physical slider at whatever value it was prior. So, if the slider was at the far right it would stay there even though the value does change to zero.

What can I do to fix this, is there a `reset` I can call instead of `.value = "0"`?

Comment: It should work, Check out the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/a14qt93r/). There must be something else wrong with your code, we need to see some more code.

Comment: Works on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/httfg8aL/) for me in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 2):

I've just found this out for jquery mobile they require a refresh for the visual styling. Here's what they say in [this](https://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/#method-refresh) page:

"If you manipulate a slider via JavaScript, you must call the refresh method on it to update the visual styling."

That solved it for me.

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "refresh" );
```